# String to Blob comparison in MySQL where clause

Tags: mysql, blob

I have a table called messages with a column (BLOB) called message_text.  I'm passing a value from the web app when a user sends a new message and I want to check if it's an exact duplicate message text.

```
SELECT count(message_id) FROM messages WHERE message_text = '$msgTxt' AND user_id = $userId
```

Where $msgTxt will be a formatted string like...

```
"Hello there. I don\'t know you. 

I\'ve just made a new line. "
```

The problem is that the comparison isn't working and I'm never finding duplicates.  Even if I literally copy/paste an existing value from the database and replace it with $msgTxt in my query I never get any results, and so I'm assuming there's something wrong with the way I'm comparing a blob to a string.

Comment: you need to convert your text first

Comment: thanks ketrox, but any ideas how?  I've experimented with using CONVERT and CAST on the message_text column but so far I still can't get an even comparison

Answer (score 0):

BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have the binary character set and collation, and comparison and sorting are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values. String or Text values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set other than binary, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set.

So, you have to convert either BLOB to String or String to BLOB and then compare both.

If you are using java,

Convert Blob to String

byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());

String data1 = new String(bdata);

Comment: thanks for the background DIksha but I'm working with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

What API are you using to call MySQL?  I see some backslashes, but need to verify that `\` is not turning into `\\`, and that other escapings are not unnecessarily happening or not happening.

Which OS are you using?  Windows, when reading stuff, likes to convert NL into CRLF, thereby making it so that it won't match.